# CKeditor5 when used as editor for civimail Traditional mailings does not save draft content

Tags: civimail, drupal-9, ckeditor5

Using CKEditor5 for civimail.   Content and images are not saved when saving draft or any save of message.

Using D9 with Civi 5.44.   CKeditor4 saves correctly as well as text editor.

Also, CKEditor5 saves content for Contributions and Memberships.   No obvious errors in Drupal Error log or other OS logfiles.

This error from console:
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://nbcore-d9-sb3.nbops.net/libraries/civicrm/core/bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE.   These do not show for Memberships or Contributions Console.

Anyone suggestions about what might be different between CKEditor usage in Civimail as compared to Memberships and Contributions?  Or what if these console errors are the issue?